# ASP.NET sessionID will not update

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpcontext, sessionid

I click on refresh button which should restart session:

```
protected void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
    HttpCookie mycookie = new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId");
    mycookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
    Response.Cookies.Add(mycookie);
    LblSessionID.Text = HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID+
        " test btnRefresh_Click";
    LblIsNewSession.Text = Session.IsNewSession.ToString();
}
```

But when the button is clicked, the SessionID value in `LblSessionID` still displays the old value but another label `LblIsNewSession` will show it as true for IsNewSession. The `LblSessionID` will then reflect the actual SessionID value when I use asp.net control (like dropdown) that has `autopostback="true"` and from there SessionID sticks around.

I do use global.asax

Any idea why `LblSessionID` isn't behaving as it should and is waiting for next postback to start reflecting actual value?

When I launch the web application, the problem is the same - `LblSessionID` show different value and then change after first postback and stays the same from there.

Comment: SessionID's are reused, and often you'll get the same id over and over again.

Comment: Use session_end event of glabal.asax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the way it works - If you `Abandon` the session it won't reflect that until the next Request. It makes sense if you think about it...

Say you have a user that accesses your site and gets a Session ID of `123` (not reflective of an actual value, I know). When you click your button to get a new Session ID, the user's request is from the old Session, and that is the value that is reflected during that `Request`. Once the session is reset (or abandoned or whatever), the user gets a new Session ID of `321` and subsequent `Request`'s will then reflect that new session ID.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer makes sense very much. I'm still not sure what is wrong with my code though. What is about this code that is not sending request and what should be added?

Answer (score 0):

SessionId is not reliable unless you actually store something (anything) in the session.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
   Session.RemoveAll();

    Session.Clear();
```

Comment: This is not going to help much - it will just remove everything from session, but will not change ID for this request.

Comment: no, these don't start new SessionID, they just clear session values

Answer (score 0):

It is not your code, it is a documented behavior: 
*"The Abandon method sets a flag in the session state object that indicates that the session state should be abandoned. The flag is examined at the end of the page request. Therefore, the user can still use session objects after you call the Abandon method. As soon as the page processing is completed, the session is removed."*
(source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/899918)

The Abandon() method flags the session collection for clearing at the end of the request, it does not actually clear it immediately.

You can either call the RemoveAll() or Clear() methods for instant deletion of the objects, or issue a Response.Redirect call to the page itself and re-test for the existence of the data.